# How to remove zeros on PHP date for 1-9?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, time

I want to remove zeros in PHP date for 1-9.

My Code:

```
    //Note : I change to Indonesian Format date.

    $hari = array ("Minggu","Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu");
    $bulan = array ("Januari","Februari","Maret","April","Mei","Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember");
    $waktu[0]=$hari[date("w",time())];
    $waktu[1]=date("d",time());
    $waktu[2]=date("m",time());
    $waktu[3]=date("Y",time());
    $waktu[4]=date("H",time());
    $waktu[5]=date("i",time());
    $waktu[6]=date("s",time());
    $hariini="$waktu[0]";
    $tanggalini="$waktu[1] ".$bulan[$waktu[2]-1]." $waktu[3]";
    $jamini="$waktu[4]:$waktu[5]:$waktu[6]";
    $today = $waktu[0].", ".$tanggalini;

    echo $today;
```

the result of this is `Kamis, 01 Februari 2018`.
See here for the numbers 1 through 9 will have 0 to the left.

How can I turn it into `Kamis, 1 Februari 2018`, without 0?

Comment: Use `j` instead of `d`: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: search before asking questions..

Comment: `date("d",time());` RTFM what 2nd parameter is in `date()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$waktu[1]=date("j",time());
```

instead of

```
$waktu[1]=date("d",time());
```

Comment: Thanks @LaritNarde

Answer (score 1):

Use date format `j` for retrieve date without leading `0`

change

```
$waktu[1]=date("d",time());
```

to

```
$waktu[1]=date("j",time());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
$waktu[1]=date("j",time());
```